# show the result based on the selection - js

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on google column charts.Requirement is based on the radio button selection, i need to show the stacked columns in the chart. When the radio button few is selected , i should not show the shipping stack in the column chart, but on mouseover the shipping and it details should be shown.
Demo plunker : [click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/aUMeUGNJYIhbNVmNFhuO?p=preview)

html code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-google-chart.js"></script>
  <title>Angular-Google-Charts Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
<div>    <tr>
  <td>ALL <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="all" ng-checked="true" ng-change='newValue(value)'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      SDL(server,desktop,laptop): <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="few" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
    </td>
        </tr></div>

    <div google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.newValue = function(value) {
        alert("change : "  + value);
        console.log(value);
    }

    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January"
        }, {
          v: 19,
          f: "42 items"
        }, {
          v: 12,
          f: "Ony 12 items"
        }, {
          v: 7,
          f: "7 servers"
        }, {
          v: 4
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12
        }, {
          v: 2
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }]
    };

    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
       focusTarget: 'category',
      "displayExactValues": true,
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      }
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;
  }).value('googleChartApiConfig', {
    version: '1.1',
    optionalSettings: {
      packages: ['bar'],
      language: 'en'
    }
  });
```

ANy suggestions would be helpful. By default ALL radio button is selected and it should show all the stacked bars in the column chart, but when user selects Few radio button, "shipping stacked bar" should be hidden but on mouse over it should be shown on the tooltip.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/H5dJ2uy6UlJh4mkN30FK?p=preview), I think this is what you need

```
var variableCol = {
      id: "cost-id",
      label: "Shipping",
      type: "number"
    };

if (value == 'few' && chart1.data.cols.length == 5) {
          chart1.data.cols.pop();
        } else {
          chart1.data.cols.push(variableCol);
        }
```

For displaying data on mouse hover, you can go thorugh google chart if it provides some option as I have not worked on google chart.

But if google chart does not provide any option you might create a directive to handle mouse enter and mouse leave events on element having google-chart directive and update the chart1.data.cols on mouse enter and leave events in that directive.

Comment: You can also use ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave directives of angular in case you do not want to create custom directive

Comment: Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/J8I4ZSrIjAj5Wp2gEUEs?p=preview ,i want to hide data for Laptop which is not working as per your suggestion above. Please suggest.@Harpreet

Comment: I think there are two types of laptop data and the one type is getting hidden for which code is written, means the code is behaving as expected as per my understanding or you can elaborate your query a bit  more